# Analysis with twitter Data

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, flume, flume-twitter

flume-twitter.conf

[flume-twitter.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nRVg.jpg)

If I want to get log files from multiple website that are merged under one company and all have their own websites, How will I add the 4 important keys (consumerkey, consumer secret,,access token,. access secret etc..) into flume-twitter.conf so that I do my analysis with different key words with all merged company websites.? Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

INstead of that you could start 4 flume agents F1, F2, F3 and F4 each one using one key. Then all 4 of them send data to 5th flume agent listening on avro. and you do your analysis logic in the 5th agent.
https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#consolidation